# Variable String in Formula R1C1

Tags: string, vba, excel, variables, excel-r1c1-notation

I am trying to create a formula using R1C1 format that will change based on a string containing a variable. I have tried creating the string and inputting it in the formula, as well as creating the string in the formula and none seems to work. Below is my code:

```
Dim NewXX As Integer
Dim NewXX1 As Integer
Dim CE As Integer
Dim PrevCE As Integer
Dim CEText As String

CE = Cells(NewXX - 1, 1).Value + 1
CEText = "=" & CE

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=SUMIFS(R[-209]C8:R[1]C8,R[-209]C1:R[1]C1,CEText,R[-209]C2:R[1]C2,""<>Summary"")*(1+R1C16)"
```

CEText is the variable that will change every time the macro is run. A few things I have tried:
CEText
""CEText"",
'"&CEText&"',
"CEText",
""="""&CE&",
""=""CE,

All of these trials either give me an 'Expected: end of statement' error, or the formula displayed in the cells matches the text (not value) found in the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am fairly new to VBA and am always up for learning a better way to do things!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CEText` is not need when you are equating and since CE is a number, we only need to worry about removing from formula string and concatenating:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=SUMIFS(R[-209]C8:R[1]C8,R[-209]C1:R[1]C1," & CE & ",R[-209]C2:R[1]C2,""<>Summary"")*(1+R1C16)"
```

If you want `CEText` then we do the extra quotes in the formula:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=SUMIFS(R[-209]C8:R[1]C8,R[-209]C1:R[1]C1,""" & CEText & """,R[-209]C2:R[1]C2,""<>Summary"")*(1+R1C16)"
```

The main issue is that any vba variable must be outside the quotes and concatenated with `&`

Comment: Thank you Scott! The second option you suggested worked perfectly!